# How do folks generate custom unique numbers when saving a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

At the place I work, quotation numbers have the form Qyyyymmddnnnn, and they want me to preserve the semantic information (that the quote number encodes the date it was issued;  nnnn resets to 0001 for the first quote issued on any day, nnnn is one larger than the same day's previous quote otherwise). How do I make Django generate such a quotenumber when a new Quote is saved?

I'm thinking along the lines

```
class Quote( models.model):

   quotenumber = models.CharField( 
                  max_length=13, unique=True ) # Qyyyymmddnnnn
   created_on = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True)
   # other fields

   # how to auto-fill the quotenumber if we're saving a new quote? Maybe

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if self.pk is None; # it's a new quote being saved
          prev_quote = Quote.objects.order_by("-quotenumber")[0]
          today=date.today()
          # generate new_quote_number from prev_quote.quotenumber and today's date
          self.quotenumber = new_quote_number

      super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Things I'm not sure about:

Is it possible to refer to the Quote class from inside itself to get hold of the current most recent quote? (Both a Python question and a Django one)

Would it be better to have a separate model / DB table containing just one row containing the current next free 4-digit number and the date on which it is valid, rather than hitting the large table of all quotes ever issued?

Is testing `self.pk is None` the right way to tell if we're saving a new record rather than updating an existing one? Or would it be better to default quotenumber to something impossible like all-zeros, and test for that default?

Comment: For what it's worth, when I need a globally unique identifier without referring to the central data store to find the next auto-incrementing PK, I'll use a [uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html)

Comment: Fair enough, but here we don't need globally unique, just unique to one table of one organisation's database.  And we do need speakable-on-telephone and hand-writeable with reasonably low error rates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can query the `Quote` model from within its methods. You may want to use [latest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#latest) for convenience.

I wouldn't use a separate table to store the latest number, that will increase the complexity. One thing you need to worry about is concurrency, to deal with the possibility that two different quotes may be created simultaneously, trying to save the same quote number. You can use a technique similar to [what someone used for creating slugs](https://keyerror.com/blog/automatically-generating-unique-slugs-in-django). The only thing I would do different would be to `try` the save, to make sure there are no errors. Something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        prev_quote = Quote.objects.latest()
        #logic to generate quote number using date and prev_quote
        self.quotenumber = new_quote_number
        fixed = self.quotenumber[:9]   # Qyyyymmdd component
        n = int(self.quotenumber[9:])  # nnnn component
        for x in itertools.count(n):
            try:
                super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            except IntegrityError:
                self.quotenumber = fixed + str(n+1).zfill(4)
            else:
                break
    else:
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```